# POST with Jquery to a php function in wordpress retrieves only empty values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

in a "wordpress" page I have this code:

```
function displayData(id) {
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          data:{rid:id},
          url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/?page_id=123",
          success: function(value) {
            alert('<?php echo($_POST['rid'])  ?>');
          }
        });
}
```

but the value displayed in alert is empty. How can get 'rid' value?

Thanks,
julio

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to change the post variable via the ajax call, but the POST['rid'] is being called when the page is loaded, before the ajax call, and won't change until the page is reloaded.  Try returning the value you want in the ajax response.

Comment: I'm trying to make an async call to a "php" function included in the same page replacing "echo" with a method name and passing the parameter "rid". But at the moment I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to retrieve a POST value via PHP in Javascript. This is erroneous. To do correctly, the PHP/Server-side script returns the value in either raw form, HTML or json. This result is returned as data to jQuery's AJAX method. Notice the variable `value` in the code below.

```
  function displayData(id) {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:{rid:id},
              url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/?page_id=123",
              success: function(value) {
                //do something with 'value'
                alert(value);
                console.log('The result is ' + value);

              }
            });
    }
```

Comment: yes u r right, but the "value" displayed in that way is the "html code" of the current page.

Comment: You need to recognize that the request being sent to the page is an being made by javascript [send something like ajax=true], and when this is the case, then send only your response [Raw, HTML or json]. This is how AJAX works, the response is the result of the page you are requesting.

Comment: This might help you out: http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/introduction-to-ajax-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

the line:

```
alert('<?php echo($_POST['rid'])  ?>');
```

will be rendered before the ajax call is made - where is the 'rid' value, in the page where the javascript lives, or the response you get from the ajax call? (ie. mywebsite.com/?page_id=123).

if its from the page you're posting data too, the response from the server would need to return a string or json object (or similar) which contains the data so you can parse it in the success value.

Comment: yes, I would like executing an async call in the page replacing "echo" with a php-method code in the same page, passing the parameter 'rid'

Comment: @Randomize - You can't make a call to a PHP function from JavaScript, once the page has loaded.  You would have to make an HTTP request to your server in order to invoke server-side functionality.  For now, I would suggest putting your PHP function in a different PHP file as this may be easier to think through.